# Bring React Native app Background to Foreground

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Using `PushNotification` from the lib `react-native-push-notification`. When we get new notification and app in background need to bring back app as foreground, without any interaction. We used `Linking.openURL('my-awesome-app://')`, but this work when app foreground but not in background.

```js
localNotification(info) {
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      channelId: 'reminders',
      title: '',
      userInteraction: true, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was opened by the user from the notification area or not
      message: info.message,
      // userInfo: info.data,
    });
    const orderDetails = JSON.stringify(info);

    const link = `my-awesome-app://Private/OrderSummeryScreen/${orderDetails}`;
    Linking.openURL(link)
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to bring the app to the foreground without having the user clicking on the notification?

Comment: yes !, without user click  @Y.Gherbi

Comment: this is generally not possible, I wrote an answer explaining why and how this works. hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React Native, background operation largely depends on the platform (iOS/Android) and its limitations. Android supports a broader range of background operation compared to iOS.

When a push notification arrives, and you want to bring your app to the foreground, this is typically done by the user clicking on the notification. In Android, you may use a `HeadlessJS` task to run some code when a notification arrives, but automatically bringing an app to the foreground without any user interaction is generally against both Android and iOS guidelines for app behavior.

**On iOS, this is simply not possible due to the strict nature of iOS's background limitations.**

On Android, it could be technically possible by creating an activity in the native code (Java/Kotlin) and launching it, but as mentioned before,
**this goes against Android guidelines and such behavior could result in your app being removed from the Google Play Store.**

You can set up your notification to navigate to a specific screen within your app once the notification is clicked using deep linking. You're already doing something similar with `Linking.openURL(link)`, but this doesn't force your app to the foreground. It only works when the app is in the foreground or if the user interacts with a notification or a link to your app.